# jQuery: Easy way to check if a href attribute is valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am looking for a pretty easy way to check when somebody clicks a link that it's valid.

Good

```
 <a href="index.html">some link</a>
```

Bad:

```
<a href="#">some link</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">some link</a>
```

Comment: use regex for your specific format

Comment: Yes but all that i found where patterns that check a complete url, included the 'http://www.', this is not going to work for urls like index.html :-) (didn't found any patterns for this yes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just check for the `href` value:

```
$('a').click(function(){
  var bad = this.href.lastIndexOf('#') >= 0 || this.href.indexOf('javascript') >= 0;
  alert(bad ? 'Bad' : 'Good');
  return false;
});
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ukuhis)

Comment: Nice but this gives of a true and false value when using # or javascript:void(0)

Comment: then use it? ;) you have not specified what the output should be but only that you want to validate it

Comment: Ah this works perfect, not that simple but it will do, thanks!!

Comment: but in this code `<a href="index.html#javascript">link</a>` would be invalid in `this.href.lastIndexOf('#') >= 0` and `this.href.indexOf('javascript') >= 0`, but I think this should evaluate valid... no?

Answer (score 3):

There is no really "easy" way, you have to get the value of the href and do an ajax call to it like so :

```
var url = $('a').attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        type:'HEAD',
        error: function()
        {
            //file not exists
        },
        success: function()
        {
            //file exists
        }
    });
```