# html link element event on GET failed

Tags: javascript, url, get, href

I've been trying to find a way to call a function if an HTML link element GET fails. In the console I can see the following if the GET fails:
[image]

and I have been trying the following:

```
<a href="http://y.i" onerror="console.log('err')"></a>
```

but it doesn't seem to work, any idea how I might solve this issue?

```html
<a href="http://y.i"  target="_blank" onerror="console.log('err')">wrong link</a>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery: Easy way to check if a href attribute is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212882/jquery-easy-way-to-check-if-a-href-attribute-is-valid)

Comment: @BryanDellinger strangely not, even if the url is a valid url like https://www.google.com, the ajax response is always an error